# find(:first) and find(:all) are deprecated

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using `RubyMine` with `rails 3.2.12` and I am getting following deprecated warning in my IDE. Any Idea How can I solve this deprecated warning?

```
find(:first) and find(:all) are deprecated in favour of first and all methods. Support will be removed from rails 3.2.
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I changed my answer after @keithepley comment

```
#Post.find(:all, :conditions => { :approved => true })
Post.where(:approved => true).all

#Post.find(:first, :conditions => { :approved => true })
Post.where(:approved => true).first
or
post = Post.first  or post = Post.first!
or
post = Post.last   or post = Post.last!
```

You can read more from [this locations](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/07/the-way-to-rails-3/)

#### deprecated statement

```
Post.find(:all, :conditions => { :approved => true })
```

#### better version

```
Post.all(:conditions => { :approved => true })
```

#### best version (1)

```
named_scope :approved, :conditions => { :approved => true }
Post.approved.all
```

#### best version (2)

```
Post.scoped(:conditions => { :approved => true }).all
```

Comment: The question's about Rails 3, but this is all outdated Rails 2 syntax. named_scope, scoped, and all with the hash like that are all old.

Comment: @keithepley - you are right, I checked in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html, thanks

Answer (score 4):

Here is the Rails 3-4 way of doing it:

```
Post.where(approved: true) # All accepted posts
Post.find_by_approved(true) # The first accepted post
# Or Post.find_by(approved: true)
# Or Post.where(approved: true).first
Post.first
Post.last
Post.all
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the new `ActiveRecord::Relation` stuff that was added in Rails 3. Find more info here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Instead of `#find`, use `#first`, `#last`, `#all`, etc. on your model, and the methods that return a ActiveRecord::Relation, like `#where`.

```
#User.find(:first)
User.first

#User.find(:all, :conditions => {:foo => true})
User.where(:foo => true).all
```

Comment: Is there a difference between `User.where(:foo => true).all` and `User.all(:conditions => {:foo => true})` ?

Comment: As for the return value, no (in Rails 2 and 3). Rails 4 will return an ActiveRecord::Relation instead. The conditions hash is deprecated though