# Updating Activerecord queries to rails 3.2 format : find(:all) to all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am updating the active record queries of a rails project. I have not been able to find out how to update when the query is
 `foo.find(:all, :stuff, :id, :thing, @bar)`

I would know how to handle a regular.`find(:all)` or `.find(:all, :conditions => {}` ([find(:first) and find(:all) are deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098961/findfirst-and-findall-are-deprecated)) but have not found anything on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, for example, your model is User, to find all users you would use:

```
User.all
```

and for specific conditions, you would use:

```
User.where(neck: "long")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [where](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions):

```
Foo.where(:stuff => stuff, :thing => thing)
#  or
Foo.where("stuff = ? AND thing = ?", stuff, thing)
```

*Also see [Rails .where vs .find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574659/rails-where-vs-find)...*

To find all (again as a `ActiveRecord::Relation` object, rather than an array)  you can use [scoped](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes):

```
Foo.scoped
```

Comment: What function does the string serve?

Comment: @Btuman it's to fight SQL injection (it's recommended in the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions)).

Comment: I thought  .where() is to convert the :conditional => {} to the current format exclusively, am I missing something?

Comment: @Btuman the scoped thing is usually preferred, since it only hits the database when needed, e.g. Foo.scoped.first only *retrieves* the first element from the db, unlike Foo.all.first which retrieves all Foos.