# Recommended way to find a record in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can see that the `find` method is now `deprecated` in rails. So what is the recommended way now?

```
Room.find(params[:id]
```

Even though 
`Room.find_by_id(params[:id])` works just want to know the recommended way

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['ActiveRecord::Core::ClassMethods.find' call is deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36480425/activerecordcoreclassmethods-find-call-is-deprecated)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [find(:first) and find(:all) are deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098961/findfirst-and-findall-are-deprecated)

Comment: `.find(id)` is not depreciated and is in fact the recommended way.

Comment: @max But the docs also mentions its deprecated http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find/class

Comment: @Abhilash it was changed and moved to `Core`, not deprecated, see http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Core/ClassMethods/find

Comment: Actually it is in  [ActiveRecord::FinderMethods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find). APIDock is not the official documentation for Rails and is often quite misleading.

Comment: Indeed it is..First rubymine throws the deprecated warning after I updated it today and when I saw the doc that mentioned its deprecrated.. Thank you all for the clarifiaction..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SomeModel.find(id)` is not deprecated.

Deprecated is the old pre-rails-3 behavior of it:

```
SomeModel.find(:all, :conditions => { :approved => true })
```